new to react native not able to get rid of these errors:
ERROR  Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().
Ensure you have:

imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.

Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list.


See http://invertase.link/android for full setup instructions., js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes

what should i do ?,i tried alot but not able to solve it.
